# How to write a shift register in a recursive way

Tags: verilog

I would like to know if there is a recursive way to write a shift register having already the module of a Flip-Flop?

```
module DFF_N(Q,D,CK);
    output Q;
    input D,CK;
    reg Q;
    always @(negedge CK) begin
       Q<=D;     
    end
endmodule
```

I want to use this module to create a shift register like this:

```
`include "DFF_N.v"

module shift_reg(Q,D,CK);
    output [10:1] Q;
    input D,CK;

    DFF_N FFN_1(Q[1],D,CK);
    DFF_N FFN_2(Q[2],Q[1],CK);
    DFF_N FFN_3(Q[3],Q[2],CK);
    DFF_N FFN_4(Q[4],Q[3],CK);
    DFF_N FFN_5(Q[5],Q[4],CK);
    DFF_N FFN_6(Q[6],Q[5],CK);
    DFF_N FFN_7(Q[7],Q[6],CK);
    DFF_N FFN_8(Q[8],Q[7],CK);
    DFF_N FFN_9(Q[9],Q[8],CK);
    DFF_N FFN_10(Q[10],Q[9],CK);
endmodule
```

Is there an easier way to write it without having to change manually the name of each `FFN_i`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a `generate` block with a `for` loop:

```
module shift_reg(Q,D,CK);
    output [10:1] Q;
    input D,CK;

    genvar i;
    generate
        for (i=1; i<=10; i=i+1) begin : shifter
            if (i==1) begin
                DFF_N FFN (Q[i], D, CK);
            end else begin
                DFF_N FFN (Q[i], Q[i-1], CK);
            end
        end
    endgenerate
endmodule
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 27.3 *Generate construct syntax*.

This can be easily scaled to different register widths, especially if you use a `parameter` instead of `10`.